# In which direction plants' root grow in weightlessness?

Tags: botany

As far as I know, roots of plants grow to the direction of Earth's gravity - this is called gravitropism.

But what happens if plants are in space? Are they able to perceive gravity in state of weightlessness? Either way, where do they grow their roots in those circumstances?

*Note: this question may fit better either to Space.SE or to Astronomy.SE, but I was not sure about it.*

Comment: @TheLastWord I couldn't use Stack Exchange for a very long time because of various reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Astronomers on the International space station have done exactly that and grown Arabidopsis Thaliana in space. You can read the whole article [here](http://news.nationalgeographic.co.in/news/2012/121207-plants-grow-space-station-science/).
Plant roots apparently grow away from the seed exactly like on earth seeking out nutrients.

Comment: either you or me should remove the answer because both are exactly the same.. I am removing mine but take care not to post an answer that is exactly same as a previous one.

Comment: but wasn't mine listed before yours..

Comment: well.. the listing it seems is not chronological. When I posted there was no answer. Nevermind. The objective is achieved. Mission accomplished :)

Comment: It is actually. When I started typing, there was no answer listed.. You started answering after me but submitted before me.. But yes Mission accomplished.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Roots are negatively phototropic in addition to being positively gravitropic. Both growth patterns are mediated by the same hormone, auxin. Removing one factor or the other will not prevent roots from growing "down."